# Configuring Tracing for Datadog in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, monitoring, datadog

I have a Spring Boot application and want to configure HTTP request tracing via dependency management without having to deal with setting up the java agent. Can anyone suggest the best way to do this?

I have the `micrometer-registry-datadog` dependency added to my pom and can see that there are a lot of undocumented `com.datadoghq` dependencies, but am unsure if any of these will solve my problem. I'm getting all of the JVM metrics, but want some more APM-type metrics now. Ideally I'd like to use the `@Timed` annotation and various others to get detailed metrics around API calls.

Comment: can you elaborate `APM-type metrics` ? Basically, datadog will create a lot of metrics based on your API tracing as well.

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: Any updates on this?